# R: List of indices to binary matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

Say I have a list of indices, like:

```
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(1), c(1,5), c(2, 3, 5))
```

Which specify the non-zero elements in a matrix, like:

```
(m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,5, 0,1,1,0,1), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    5
[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
```

What is the fastest way, using R, to make `m` from `l`, giving that the matrix is very big, say 50.000 rows and 2000 columns?

Comment: How do you know when to put, say, 5?

Comment: I am guessing the value `5` is a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
d1 <- stack(setNames(l, seq_along(l)))
library(Matrix)
m1 <- sparseMatrix(as.numeric(d1[,2]), d1[,1], x=1)
as.matrix(m1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    1    1    0    1
```

Or instead of `stack`, we could use `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
d2 <- melt(l)
sparseMatrix(d2[,2], d2[,1],x=1)
```

Or using only `base R`

```
Un1 <- unlist(l)
m1 <- matrix(0, nrow=length(l), ncol=max(Un1))
m1[cbind(as.numeric(d1$ind), d1$values)] <- 1
m1
```

Comment: Love the matrix indexing in your third attempt. My favorite little-used feature of R!

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the comments.  I think the `sparseMatrix` would be faster than the indexing.

Comment: Thanks, all of these are helpful!

Comment: @akrun: I'd think so too.

Comment: What about empty list elements? added this an edit in the original post

Comment: @Misconstruction Please post that as a separate question as your original question is already solved

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following is at least 3 times faster than the suggestions above, on data the size as specified in the question (5e4 x 2e3):

```
  unlist_l <- unlist(l)
  M <- matrix(0, nrow = length(l), ncol = max(unique(unlist_l)))
  ij <- cbind(rep(1:length(l), lengths(l)), unlist_l)
  M[ij] <- 1
```

Performance might depend on data size and degree of sparsity.